# ServiceStack with Angular (9) compilation error after upgrade from 1.0.46 to 1.0.47

Tags: angular, servicestack

In our package.json we used `^` to declare the package reference `@servicestack/client`. Since the last update of the ServiceStack repo to the new version `1.0.47` we get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'MyProjectPath...\node_modules\@servicestack\client\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'MyProjectPath...\node_modules\@servicestack\client\dist'
```

If we define the version in our `package.json` fix to `@servicestack/client": "1.0.46` the build runs fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Angular's AOT compiler still does static reference evaluation for code that it doesn't run at runtime. v1.0.48 works around this by using a dyanmic require resolution.

This is now available from latest `@servicestack/client` that's now on npm

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@servicestack/client": "^1.0.48",
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now with `1.0.48`.